# Neo4j using optiona and null

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute this query.

```
OPTIONAL match
(email:EMAIL)<-[r:REGISTERED_WITH]-(customer_bseller:CUSTOMER_BSELLER)-[addr_r:ADDRESS{shipping:'true'}]->(addr:ADDRESS)
with email, customer_bseller, addr   
OPTIONAL match (pedida_user:PEDIDA_DE_HOJE_USER)-[r1:REGISTERED_WITH]->(email)<-[r2:REGISTERED_WITH]-(customer_bseller)
where pedida_user IS NOT NULL 
return distinct customer_bseller,
pedida_user limit 5
```

The problem is that the result set is comming with pedida_user NULL.

Is this the correct way to test if a id is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `pedida_user` identifier is defined by an `OPTIONAL MATCH`, it is perfectly possible for your `RETURN` clause to contain a NULL `pedida_user` value.

Comment: So how to avoid returning NULL?

Comment: You need to explain clearly what your data model is and what you are trying to achieve.